# Script alert error message in JMeter recording

Tags: javascript, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I have recorded the JMeter script from blazemeter. It is working fine in website. When i run the jmx file Its throwing an error below..

"alert("Something went wrong. Please try again");window.history.back();"

This is the issue with JMeter script or application. I am getting response from server 200.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your script lacks [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter) of the dynamic parameters (or it's not working properly)

In the majority of cases you won't be able to just replay recorded script, modern web applications heavily rely on dynamic parameters for establishing [user session](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), tracking [client side state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb386448(v=vs.100)), [security reasons](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf/tokens) and so on.

So you need to identify all the parameters, extract them using suitable [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and replace recorded hard-coded values with the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) originating from the Post-Processors.

And don't forget to add HTTP Cookie Manager to your test plan if it's not there yet.